# Use Select to filter a dataset's sublists

Tags: dataset, associations, filtering, homework

In the following `Dataset`, I want to use `Select` to display only rows, which contain numbers in column `c` that are even. These elements don't all have to be even, but at least one in each row. Basically so that the only rows that are removed are the ones that have only odd numbers in `c`.

```
dataq = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 13, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {1, 8, 6, 9}|>, <|
"a" -> 24, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "d", 
"c" -> {4, 5}|>, <|"a" -> 32, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {3, 8, 9}|>, <|
"a" -> 8, "b" -> "n", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>, <|"a" -> 19, "b" -> "x",
 "c" -> {1}|>}]
```

The farthest I've gotten is with `MemberQ`, but how do you condition that on an `EvenQ` condition instead of a number:

```
dataq=[Select[MemberQ[#c, 5] &]]
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Sticking with your origination approach this does the job for you: `dataq[Select[MemberQ[#c, _?EvenQ] &]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    dataq[Select[AnyTrue[#c, EvenQ] &]]
```

Comment: Beat me to it, I was going to post `Select[dataq, (Or @@ EvenQ[#c]) &]` - slightly different but mostly the same

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if that's the way to go in general but in 10.4 `KeyValuePattern` was introduced:

```
DeleteCases[
 dataq,
 KeyValuePattern["c" -> {__?OddQ}]
]
```

> [image]